# Delete Duplicates in Array based on matching id. Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I've got a `.csv` file that I've imported into an array. They're all comma separated so I've gone ahead and made a nice array for em.

Now I'm trying to find records with matching id's so I can remove duplicates and only keep the last encountered. Using `ID` for instance.

I've imported to array but for some reason I can't get a tool like uniq to display the new unique list even though when I do .length on it, it returns the right amount of rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
    lines = []
    i = 0

    file = File.open("./properties.csv", "r")

    elements = Array[]
    element2 = Array[]
    output = Array[]

    while (line = file.gets)
        i += 1
      # use split to break array up using commas
        arr = line.split(',')
        elements.push({ id: arr[0], streetAddress: arr[1], town: arr[2], valuationDate: arr[3], value: arr[4] })
    end

    file.close

    # Loop through array and sort nicely
     element2 = elements.group_by { |c| c[:id] }.values.select { |elements| elements.size > 1 }


    output = (element2.uniq)
    puts output

    puts element2.length
```

SAMPLE .CSV FILE

```
ID,Street address,Town,Valuation date,Value
1,1 Northburn RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
2,1 Mount Ida PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
3,1 Mount Linton AVE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
1,1 Northburn RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,330000
2,1 Mount Ida PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,330000
3,1 Mount Linton AVE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,830000
1,1 Northburn RD,WANAKA,1/1/2016,340000
2,1 Mount Ida PL,WANAKA,1/1/2016,340000
3,1 Mount Linton AVE,WANAKA,1/1/2016,840000
4,1 Kamahi ST,WANAKA,1/1/2016,215000
5,1 Kapuka LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2016,209000
6,1 Mohua MEWS,WANAKA,1/1/2016,620000
7,1 Kakapo CT,WANAKA,1/1/2016,490000
8,1 Mt Gold PL,WANAKA,1/1/2016,1320000
9,1 Penrith Park DR,WANAKA,1/1/2016,1310000
```

Comment: You probably mean `[]` instead of `Array[]`.

Comment: that's true! But correct me here if I'm wrong but isn't that a distinction without a difference?

Comment: The difference is using `Array[]` is just plain bizarre. Using the simplest expression is generally the best.

Comment: haha thanks for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've actually swapped my approach to using hashes. which seems to automatically remove duplicates and leave the last encountered record intact? Can anyone shed some light here?

```
    require 'csv'

    element = {}

    CSV.foreach("properties.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
        element[row.fields[0]] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
    end

    puts element["1"]

    element.each do |key, value|
        puts key 
        puts value
    end

    puts "#{element.length} records returned"
```

To keep the first matching element, instead of the last, you can do a key existence check before assigning the value.  This can be done like so:

```
CSV.foreach("properties.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  key = row.fields[0]
  if !element.key?(key)
    element[key] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
  end
end
```

which can also be written much more efficiently like this:

```
CSV.foreach("properties.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  element[row.fields[0]] ||= Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
end
```

Note that these methods to preserve the first found record for a key will perform much better than the version that preserves the final found record for a key.  This is because of work avoidance, primarily in producing the hash value, which is done with `slice` and `zip` in this code.

Comment: Anyone know how I could reverse this so the hash only takes the first duplicate entry instead of the last encountered?

Comment: Hash uses a unique key as its index.  When you use `element[row.fields[0]]`, what you're doing is overwriting the previous value in the hash for that key.  This will give you the uniqueness, as long as you're fine with the last id value being the one that gets retained.  The new code is generations better than the original, so kudos on coming to that solution!  :D

Comment: thanks!
What if I wanted to retain the first value entered into the hash and then ignore the following?

Comment: I updated the answer with some details that show how to do that, and the benefits of preserving the first match instead of the last one.  Great follow-up question!

Comment: you are an actual legend. How do I give you "boss" points for comments/edits?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Still learning, too.  I just happened to know that bit.  :D  Good luck and have fun!

Comment: FYI, you might want to turn off tabs in your editor.  Tabs aren't recommended in code.  It's not a *problem*, but a style issue.  The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) is a fantastic resource, and will help you adopt a coding style that "fits" with the larger Ruby community.